# Transpose and split rows into columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a requirement where I have thousands of records in excel as below format.
Please note that this exist in column A and what i want to achieve is to split this in following format: Name, Street Address, City, State, Zip, PhoneNumber, ID.

Please also note that each record is seperated by two rows and consists of 4 rows. Also, a record can have a blank row like in case of Banner Inc..

Paste special is very redundant and will appreciate any help.

Thanks

```
Adv Sales 
8 Arch Street Ext 
Seaford,   DE   12073 
(302) 600-8000                 ID:12345 


XYZ Incorporated 
168 N du Pont Hwy 
New Castle,   DE   19720 
(302) 300-7000                 ID:89000 


Audi 
200 Sys Rd 
Wilmin,   DE   20001 
(302) 700-4000                 ID:71000 


Baker  
3000 Governor Printz Blvd 
Wilmington,   DE   19802 
(302) 700-3000                 ID:70000 


Banner Inc. 

Delmar,   DE   19000 
(302) 800-0000               ID:7000
```

**Update:**

*Here is the output of the code:*

```
Auto Sales  2024 E Platte Ave   Colorado    Springs,        -719    520-0995
 Auto Sales     1551 S Broadway     Cortez,     CO  -970    564-1490
```

1. State is missing when space exists in city like colorado srings.
2. first 3 digit of contact number is in different column and is minus.
3. Zip code and ID is missing.

**Latest Update:**
can you run your code with array for the following data set, please?:

```
1995 A Sales 
2024 E Platt Ave 
Colorado Springs,   CO   80909 
(719) 520-0995                 ID:70686 


4x 4 Sales 
1551 S Broadway 
Cortez,   CO   81321 
(970) 564-1490                 ID:70687 


A & I  Sales 
5030 Yo st 
Denver,   CO   80216 
(303) 756-6814                 ID:70693 


A Courtesy Auto Sales 
6000 E 49th Ave 
Commerce City,   CO   80022 
(303) 288-9472                 ID:70691 


Able Auto Sales LLC 
981 E Highway 224 
Denver,   CO   80229 
(303) 227-0175                 ID:70688
```

It gives me following error:
Run-time error'9':
Subscript out of range

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: updated. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @pnuts it is noy only a matter of transposition, but somme cells need to be split (i.e. city, state and zip are in the same cell). However, I think that Dev needs to show us his efforts first.

Comment: @pnuts you pointed out two of the faults in the post and gave wrong solution. Speecless!

Comment: @A.S.H - I wanted to know if there is a smarter way of doing this other then spltting and transposing each record at a time. So was looking for some guidelines on what will take me there. I dont need code. I just need direction on how to do it.

Comment: @A.S.H - Yes. I would like to say that all records are in one column if I missed that before. I have almost never done VBA before or cant think of anything in excel with which I can automate this and that's where I would like some suggestions.

Comment: ok, i will give you a macro, but do you know how to copy it and make it work?

Comment: Not really but I will figure it out. Thanks for your help. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another version that should run quite quickly.  It requires a Class module which you Rename cContact, and a regular module.  You can rename the class module by selecting the module; `F4` to display the properties, and then change the (Name).

You can see in the regular module where to change the worksheet names for your source data and results.  It assumes that data starts in A1, and is laid out pretty much as you show, although there is some flexibility to allow for zip+4 and phone numbers without area codes.

**Class Module**

---

```
Option Explicit
'Rename this module:  cContact

Private pName As String
Private pStreetAddress As String
Private pCity As String
Private pState As String
Private pZip As Long
Private pPhoneNumber As Variant
Private pID As Long

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = pName
End Property
Public Property Let Name(Value As String)
    pName = Value
End Property

Public Property Get StreetAddress() As String
    StreetAddress = pStreetAddress
End Property
Public Property Let StreetAddress(Value As String)
    pStreetAddress = Value
End Property

Public Property Get City() As String
    City = pCity
End Property
Public Property Let City(Value As String)
    pCity = Value
End Property

Public Property Get State() As String
    State = pState
End Property
Public Property Let State(Value As String)
    pState = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Zip() As Long
    Zip = pZip
End Property
Public Property Let Zip(Value As Long)
    pZip = Value
End Property

Public Property Get PhoneNumber() As Variant
    PhoneNumber = pPhoneNumber
End Property
Public Property Let PhoneNumber(Value As Variant)
    pPhoneNumber = Value
End Property

Public Property Get ID() As Long
    ID = pID
End Property
Public Property Let ID(Value As Long)
    pID = Value
End Property
```

---

**Regular Module**

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub ContactRowsToColumns()
    Dim cC As cContact, colC As Collection
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes() As Variant
    Dim I As Long, J As Long
    Dim S As String, S1 As String

'Alter as needed depending on worksheet names for Source data
'  and results location.

'Source data assumed to start in row 1, Column A
Set wsSrc = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set wsRes = Worksheets("sheet2")
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 1)

With wsSrc
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
End With

'Collect the data
Set colC = New Collection
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1) Step 6
    Set cC = New cContact
    With cC
        .Name = vSrc(I, 1)
        .StreetAddress = vSrc(I + 1, 1)
        S = Trim(Replace(vSrc(I + 2, 1), Chr(160), ""))
        .City = Left(S, InStr(1, S, ",") - 1)
        .State = Left(Trim(Mid(S, InStr(1, S, ",") + 1)), 2)
        .Zip = Val(Replace(Mid(Trim(S), InStrRev(Trim(S), " ") + 1), "-", ""))
            S = Trim(vSrc(I + 3, 1))
            S1 = ""
            For J = 1 To InStr(1, S, "ID") - 1
                If IsNumeric(Mid(S, J, 1)) Then S1 = S1 & Mid(S, J, 1)
            Next J
        .PhoneNumber = CDec(S1)
        .ID = Mid(S, InStr(1, S, "ID") + 3)
        colC.Add cC
    End With
Next I

'Populate results array
ReDim vRes(0 To colC.Count, 1 To 7)
vRes(0, 1) = "Name"
vRes(0, 2) = "Street Address"
vRes(0, 3) = "City"
vRes(0, 4) = "State"
vRes(0, 5) = "Zip"
vRes(0, 6) = "Phone Number"
vRes(0, 7) = "ID"

For I = 1 To colC.Count
With colC(I)
    vRes(I, 1) = .Name
    vRes(I, 2) = .StreetAddress
    vRes(I, 3) = .City
    vRes(I, 4) = .State
    vRes(I, 5) = .Zip
    vRes(I, 6) = .PhoneNumber
    vRes(I, 7) = .ID
End With
Next I

'Write results to worksheet
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    With Rows(1)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With

    .Columns(5).NumberFormat = "[<100000]00000;[>100000]00000-0000"
    .Columns(6).NumberFormat = "[<10000000]000-0000;[>10000000](000) 000-0000"
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With
End Sub
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version using arrays:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub transposeRecord()
    Const UNIT  As Byte = 4
    Const ITMS  As Byte = 6
    Const DELID As String = "ID:"
    Dim ur As Range, lr As Long, lc As Long, i As Long, v As Variant, s As Variant
        Set ur = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        lr = ur.Cells(ur.Row + ur.Rows.Count, ur.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        lc = ur.Cells(ur.Row, ur.Column + ur.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    v = ur.Range(ur.Cells(ur.Row, ur.Column), ur.Cells(lr, lc + 1 + ITMS))
    For i = 1 To lr
        v(i, ITMS - 4) = Trim(v(i + UNIT - 3, 1))       'Street Address
        If Len(v(i + UNIT - 2, 1)) > 0 Then             'City-State-Zip
            s = Split(v(i + UNIT - 2, 1), "   ")
            v(i, ITMS - 3) = Left(s(0), Len(s(0)) - 1)  'City
            v(i, ITMS - 2) = Trim(s(1))                 'State
            v(i, ITMS - 1) = Trim(s(2))                 'Zip
        End If
        If Len(v(i + UNIT - 1, 1)) > 0 Then             'PhoneNumber-ID
            s = Split(v(i + UNIT - 1, 1), DELID)
            v(i, ITMS + 0) = Trim(s(0))                 'PhoneNumber
            v(i, ITMS + 1) = DELID & Trim(s(1))         'ID
        End If
        i = i + ITMS - 1
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ur.Range(ur.Cells(ur.Row, ur.Column), ur.Cells(lr, lc + 1 + ITMS)) = v
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
            Set ur = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
            ur.AutoFilter Field:=ITMS + 1, Criteria1:="="
            ur.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
            ur.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
        ur.Cells(1).Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

[image: transposeRecord]